# How to use caffe convnet library to detect facial expressions?

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network

How can I use caffe convnet to detect facial expressions?

I have a image dataset, Cohn Kanade, and I want to train caffe convnet with this dataset. [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) has a documentation site, but its not explain how to train my own data. Just with pre trained data.

Can someone teach me how to do it?

Comment: Pasdf, I have the same problem too. I did not understand, how to traing caffe.

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to use when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caffe supports multiple formats for the input data (HDF5/lmdb/leveldb). It's just a matter of picking the one you feel most comfortable with. Here are a couple of options:

1. **caffe/build/tools/convert_imageset:**

`convert_imageset` is one of the command line tools you get from building caffe.

Usage is along the lines of:

- specifying a list of images and label pairs in a text file. 1 row per pair.
- specifying where the images are located.
- Choosing a backend db (which format). Default is lmdb which should be fine.

You need to write up a text file where each line starts with the filename of the image followed by a scalar label (e.g. 0, 1, 2,...)

2. **Construct your lmdb in python using Caffe's `Datum` class:**

This requires building caffe's python interface. Here you write some python code that:

- iterates through a list of images
- loads the images into a `numpy` array.
- Constructs a caffe `Datum` object
- Assigns the image data to the `Datum` object.
- The `Datum` class has a member called `label` you can set it to the AU class from your CK dataset, if that is what you want your network to classify.
- Writes the `Datum` object to the db and moves on to the next image.

[Here's](http://deepdish.io/2015/04/28/creating-lmdb-in-python/) a code snippet of converting images to an lmdb from a blog post by Gustav Larsson. In his example he constructs an lmdb of images and label pairs for image classification.

**Loading the lmdb into your network:**

This is done exactly like in the LeNet example. This Data layer at the beginning of the network prototxt that describes the LeNet model.

```
layer {
  name: "mnist"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  data_param {
    source: "examples/mnist/mnist_train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 64
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
```

The source field is where you point caffe to the location of the lmdb you just created.

Something more related to performance and not critical to getting this to work is specifying how to normalize the input features. This is done through the `transform_param` field. CK+ has fixed size images, so no need for resizing. One thing you do need though is normalize the grayscale values. You can do this through mean subtraction. A simple of doing this is to replace the value of `transform_param:scale` with the mean value of the gray scale intensities in your CK+ dataset.

Comment: Thanks you, ypx. Following your informations and the informations on the Gustav Larsson blog I could configure caffe.

Comment: ypx, I get that my mean value of gray scale intensities is 130, what I must put on transform_param:scale?  transform_param:130? Is it right?

Comment: @Pasdf if you want to divide gray scale values by the mean intensity, you need to add   transform_param { scale: 0.00769230769 } where 0.00769230769 = 1/130. You divide by setting the scale to the reciprocal.