# How to configure Caffe deploy.prototxt?

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network

I followed @ypx instructions on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846518/how-to-use-caffe-convnet-library-to-detect-facial-expressions?noredirect=1#comment53572955_32846518). Now I want to predict some pictures. So I'm using:

```
MODEL_FILE = '/tmp/deploy.prototxt'
PRETRAINED = '/tmp/ck.caffemodel'
IMAGE_FILE = '/tmp/img.png'

net = caffe.Classifier(MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED, image_dims=(200, 200))
```

But I get this message:

```
I1002 13:49:24.331648 28172 net.cpp:435] Input 0 -> data
I1002 13:49:24.331667 28172 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer data
I1002 13:49:24.332259 28172 net.cpp:110] Creating Layer data
F1002 13:49:24.332272 28172 net.cpp:427] Top blob 'data' produced by multiple sources.
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

I think that my problem is on my deploy.prototxt file. [This is my deploy.prototxt](https://bpaste.net/show/42874fcfbbaa) and [This is my train.prototxt](https://bpaste.net/show/b5564e0f8c04)

Can someone help me to configure my deploy file?

Comment: The links for prototxt files are now dead links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the training input layer (lines 8--21) from your deploy net.

That is, discard this:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00392156862745
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/tmp/db"
    batch_size: 64
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
```